# Creating SQLAlchemy object outside of session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to create sqlalchemy objects using the declarative approach that are "temporary" objects and are not meant to be persisted but simply compared.

As such, i would like to create them "outside" the current session. The problem is if i don't expunge them one by one, the session tries to flush them, and thus creates foreign key errors (which is normal because the objects are incomplete).

I've been using "declarative_base" from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative to create a base class, then inherit from it to create my model objects.
eg (pseudo code) :

```
class BaseEntity(object):
   ... common columns ...

Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseEntity)
class MyObject(Base):
   ... other columns ..
```

Now whenever i do :

```
tmpobj = MyObject()
```

i need to do (with session object being a scoped_session declared in another module)

```
session.expunge(tmpobj)
```

which, given the complex way my tmp objects are created (and nested to each others), is really umbersome.

Is there any special parameter i could pass to MyObject() constructor to prevent the object from beeing added to the session ?

Comment: I've just noticed that many people are asking the opposite question (how to automatically add to session), so i guess my tmp objects are associated somehow to persisted objects, somewhere and so are included automatically in the session.

Comment: Ben, I've noticed the same thing to.  Whenever I have a relationship defined and I do something like this -> user.address.append(Address(...)), the appended address is automatically added to the session for me.  It's actually a nice shortcut, except in your case :-)

Comment: Nothing about creating objects causes them to be associated with your session.  You must be doing something else that makes them persistent; probably along the lines of jaime's example.  You'll need to show us some more code that reproduces your issue, before we can help you find a convenient way to avoid it.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy and jaime : thanks, i finally found the solution to my problem and that was indeed a link to a managed object somewhere. I've posted the answer just in case someone encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so indeed, i was adding those tmp objects to managed objects, thus making them managed by the session as well.

The solution was to stop linking the tmp objects to managed objects using relationship, and  use the foreign key columns instead (i still needed to keep the information).

So, instead of doing this (in this case, using a backref relationship):

```
mytmpobject.relationobject =  aManagedRelationObject
```

do this :

```
mytmpobject.relationobject_id = aManagedRelationObject.id
```

This way, the mytmpobject stays outside the session.

Comment: And another solution was to use session.expunge_all() to expunge everything, then re-add only the part that i wanted to persist.

Comment: @Bem G - How can you get the realtionobject_id without having SQLAlchemy yell at you?